# Replicate values of column along rows

Tags: r, data.table

Given the following data frame:

```
df1 <- data.table( V1=c(0,0,0,0),V2=c(0,0,0,0),V3=c(0,2,0,2))
df1
   V1 V2 V3
1:  0  0  0
2:  0  0  2
3:  0  0  0
4:  0  0  2
```

I seek to replicate the values of V3 along the entire row, so that:

```
df2
   V1 V2 V3
1:  0  0  0
2:  2  2  2
3:  0  0  0
4:  2  2  2
```

How can I achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm... not sure, maybe just `df1[, rep(3, ncol(df1)), with = FALSE]`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I guess you are right.  I didn't check the `V3` column part.

Comment: `df1[] <- df1[["V3"]]` ?

Comment: Or `setDT(rep(list(df1$V3),3))[]`

Comment: @akrun Oh, didn't notice this was a data.table question. Yeah, that's an elegant way to go.

Comment: @Frank Your code is very elegant and compact.  Does it have any flaw wrt to data.table efficiency?

Comment: I'll just post an answer with a few options, I guess

Comment: Thank you all guys, I am learning tons of things lately. @Frank, your code does the job neatly.

Comment: may be this too  `df1[V3 != 0, 1:2 := V3, with = FALSE]`

Comment: @Frank this this is neat indeed, I think that `[]` keeping it in shallow copy level too so similar to assignment by reference I guess. Probably less typing will just `df1[] <- df1$V3`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Okay thanks, switched to `$`. Feel free to edit in any technical details. (I'm not really up on all that, though I do remember that bgoldst's favorite `DT[,"newcol"] <- val` is treated by `[.data.table`, so I guess this probably is, too.)

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar it's a bit too manual (as you need to know the column locations and the common values among them, I would go with just `df1[, 1:ncol(df1) := V3, with = FALSE]`

Comment: This is a very nice question. Provided reproducible example and desired output and certainly not a duplicate (that at least I can think of), so please refrain from downvoting it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use base-R syntax:

```
# to overwrite
df1[] <- df1$V3 

# to make a new table
df2   <- copy(df1)
df2[] <- df1$V3
```

I think the most data.table-ish way to modify so many columns is with `set`:

```
# to overwrite
for (j in setdiff(names(df1),"V3")) set(df1, j = j, value = df1$V3)

# to make a new table -- simple extension
```

Finally, there are several other good ideas from @akrun, @DavidArenburg and @VeerendraGadekar:

```
# to overwrite
df1[, (1:ncol(df1)) := V3] # David/Veerendra

# to make a new table
df2 <- setDT(rep(list(df1$V3), ncol(df1))) # akrun
df2 <- df1[, rep("V3",ncol(df1)), with = FALSE] # David
```